# Remote script can make request to server hosting the script? Same Origin Policy

Tags: javascript, html, http

If I have a server:

www.server1.com

that loads a script from:

www.server2.com/script-to-load.js

Can the script-to-load.js make an ajax call to www.server2.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are three ways to do this:

1. **CORS:** Using this method, headers are added to www.server2.com allowing access from www.server1.com. This is the "correct" way to do cross-domain scripting in JavaScript. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
2. **Use a server-side "proxy":** Using this method, a server-side script on www.server1.com accesses the file on www.server2.com and returns the response. This is a practical way to access data on a server you don't control from a website on a server you do control. An example script is below.
3. **JSONP:** This method exploits the fact that the `script` tag is exempt from cross-domain restrictions. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

---

**Example PHP "proxy" script for cross-domain scripting:**

An example PHP script to do option 2 is:

```
<?php
   ini_set("user_agent", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // temporarily override CURLs user agent with the user's own
   echo file_get_contents($_REQUEST["www"]);
?>
```

Place this script at www.server1.com/proxy.php and call http://www.server1.com/proxy.php?www=http://www.server2.com/ajax.js. The script will return the contents of www.server2.com/ajax.js, thus circumventing the cross-domain restriction.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Javascript has no conception of where a piece of code came from.

The same-origin policy is applied only based on the document that is executing the script.

Answer (score 2):

If this is server side JS (you said a server was loading a script), there are no same-origin restrictions in server-side JS.  Same-origin restrictions are implemented by browsers and affect what scripts that run in a browser can do.

Further, in a browser it does not matter where a script came from.  The browser looks at the origin of the web page and restricts ajax calls (made by any script in the page) to the domain of the web page.  Scripts can come from anywhere and their origin does not affect the browser-based same-origin restrictions on the origin of the page itself.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is a good reference on browser-based same-origin restrictions.